# How i update and delete each row of a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is the screenshot of my table :

[image]

I want to update each row and delete also using jquery.
how i dynamically do this update and delete operation.
Here is my code given bellow:

```
$.post("showEmployeeList", function(data){

    var dataTable = '<table class="table"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Update</th><th>Delete</th></tr>';

    for(var key in data){
        dataTable += '<tr><td>' + data[key].id + '</td><td>' + data[key].name + '</td><td>'
        + data[key].address + '</td><td><input type="button" id="update" value="Update" class="update" onclick="updateEmaployee()></td><td><input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="deleteEmployee()></td></tr>';
    }

    dataTable += '</table>';

    $("#divDataTable").html(dataTable);
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. What should happen if a user clicks update? If a user clicks delete the row should be deleted?

Comment: if user click update then these column are works like edittext .then i can edit here and update it. and if i click delete button then it will show alert and delete this row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var key in data){
    dataTable += '<tr><td class="id">' + data[key].id + '</td><td class="name">' + data[key].name + '</td><td class="address">'
    + data[key].address + '</td><td><input type="button" value="Update" class="update"></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete"></td></tr>';
}
```

To delete the row,

```
$(".delete").on("click",function(){
$(this).parent().parent('tr').remove();
});
```

To update the row,

```
$(".update").on("click",function(){
$(this).parent().parent('tr').find('.id').text("updated id");
$(this).parent().parent('tr').find('.name').text("updated name");
$(this).parent().parent('tr').find('.address').text("updated address");
});
```

Comment: Updated the anwser. Also there was a missing quotation mark after methods, updateEmaployee() & deleteEmployee(). But you do not need those functions if use the above method.